# HTML List structure in a PDF rendered Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, html5, renderas

I have a visualforce page which has a nested list structure. Sample code below.

## Visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="RoleStructure" showHeader="false" >

  <html>
    <apex:form >
        <ul>
          <li>Node 1</li>
          <li>Node 2</li>
               <ul>
                  <li>Node 2.1</li>
                      <ul>
                        <li>Node 2.1.1</li>
                           <ul>
                             Node 2.1.1.1
                           </ul>
                        <li>Node 2.1.2</li>
                     </ul>
                  <li>Node 2.2</li>
                     <ul>
                        <li>Node 2.2.1</li>
                            <ul>
                               Node 2.2.1.1
                            </ul>
                        <li>Node 2.2.2</li>
                     </ul>
              </ul>
        </ul> 

      </apex:form>
    </html>
   </apex:page>
```

As a normal VF page it will follow the default List styles (below)

- Node 1
- Node 2
  - Node 2.1
    - Node 2.1.1
        Node 2.1.1.1
    - Node 2.1.2
  - Node 2.2
    - Node 2.2.1
        Node 2.2.1.1
    - Node 2.2.2

But when I render the VF page as PDF, the list structure is not properly formatted (Below).

- Node 1
- Node 2
- Node 2.1
- Node 2.1.1
  Node 2.1.1.1
- Node 2.1.2
- Node 2.2
- Node 2.2.1
  Node 2.2.1.1
- Node 2.2.2

Not sure if this is a limitation of the the VF PDF rendering but is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write some conditional CSS to use for when you're rendering as a PDF. The problem you're facing is the Salesforce PDF render engine will only support CSS 2.1. The default stylesheets are enabling CSS that's beyond ver 2.1 or equivalent JS/Ajax functionality that does the expansion and contraction of your nodes. The Render engine won't recognize that active content functionality, so you'll need to duplicate it with conditional styling.

Comment: I understand. Probably creating a set of varying left padding custom styles and assigning it to the nodes depending on the branch level will do the trick. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I'll leave the CSS solution to you to suit your needs. Thus the reason I explained the problem as there are obviously numerous ways of solving this. :)